# Class similar to NSMutableDictionary in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c

I want to create a class similar to NSMutableDictionary in c++. Which datatype can i use or is there any free library available in c++.

I can't use std::map because it stores only homogenous data... I want to store heterogeneous data, can i use *Boost libraries*. Which class([list here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/index.html)) in the boost library does operation something similar to NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: You know, if you tell what NSMutableDictionary is/does, you will surely get more help. Instead of just getting help from the people that know both Objective-C and C++, you would get help from anyone that knows at least C++.

Comment: ... In particular: what _specifically_ you like about the behaviour of NSMutableDictionary, as opposed to, say, `std::map<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent for `NSMutableDictionary` in C++ but **[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)** is probably what you can make best use of.

**Reasons:**

`NSMutableDictionary`has built-in reference counted memory management, while none of the STL container classes take ownership of the contained objects if they are pointers.

So at best the equivalent C++ can provide you is a sdt::map, wherein you can store **Smart pointers** pointing to your objects.

EDIT: For hetrogeneous data items you scan use **[boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html)** with **[std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::map` using either [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html) for the heterogeneous values.

If you want the ownership semantics of `NSMutableDictionary` you can store smart pointers instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for STL [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/), wich is part of the standard and therefore available automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've [seen in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), std::map should do what you want:

See [codepad](http://codepad.org/DP6jZzSO)

```
std::map<int, std::string> map;
map[1] = "One";
map[2] = "Two";
map[3] = "Three";

std::cout << "Pick " << map[1] << std::endl;

map.insert(std::make_pair(4, "Four"));

// etc.
```

#### Hash maps

If you need optimal look up performance for large collections lookat std::unordered_map (which is part of TR1, c++0x or in boost). It requires your keys to be hashable (define a hash function for your custom types, or use the predefined one for intrinsics)